# Git checkout tag in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, git

I wanted to verify how to checkout a tag through Eclipse. So far, I cloned a github repository and I created a new branch. I want to now checkout a specific tag. I went to "Team" -> "Switch to" -> "Other" and selected the specific tag. However, I get an Eclipse pop warning box stating "You are in 'detached HEAD' state. This means that you don't have a local branch checked out...". Is this something that I need to worry about or is there a correct this? I thought by creating a new branch that this would have worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: it is expected behavior, tags are not mutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is expected behavior, tags are not mutable. If you need to change you have to create a branch from the tag.

git checkout -b branch_name tag_name

Or in eclipse, do what you just did and create a new branch.

Comment: Right, I have done this from the command line before, but from the IDE I was mixed up on how to do the same action. Perhaps, the best practice might be to switch to the tag first and then create a new branch. Do you agree?

Comment: Or, you can Team->Switch To-> new branch -> and select the tag. You may need to fetch if you cannot see the tag.